# guard init can not find such file error

Tags: ruby, rubygems, guard, jasmine-headless-webkit

I have installed guard jasmine-headless webkit but it is causing an error.
From the output I think it's the only one.

Does anyone know how to fix this, so it can find the file.

This is the output:

```
→ guard init
/Users/redres/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/pry-1.0.0.pre1/lib/pry/pry_class.rb:249: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/local/bin in PATH, mode 040777
16:13:18 - INFO - Writing new Guardfile to /Users/redres/Desktop/mailtest/Guardfile
16:13:19 - INFO - jammit guard added to Guardfile, feel free to edit it
/Users/redres/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/guard-2.4.0/lib/guard/plugin/base.rb:53:in `read': No such file or directory - /Users/redres/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/guard-jasmine-headless-webkit-0.3.2/lib/guard/jasmineheadlesswebkit/templates/Guardfile (Errno::ENOENT)
    from /Users/redres/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/guard-2.4.0/lib/guard/plugin/base.rb:53:in `template'
    from /Users/redres/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/guard-2.4.0/lib/guard/plugin_util.rb:129:in `block in add_to_guardfile'
    from /Users/redres/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/guard-2.4.0/lib/guard/plugin_util.rb:126:in `open'
    from /Users/redres/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/guard-2.4.0/lib/guard/plugin_util.rb:126:in `add_to_guardfile'
    from /Users/redres/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/guard-2.4.0/lib/guard/guardfile/generator.rb:62:in `initialize_template'
    from /Users/redres/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/guard-2.4.0/lib/guard/guardfile/generator.rb:88:in `block in initialize_all_templates'
    from /Users/redres/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/guard-2.4.0/lib/guard/guardfile/generator.rb:88:in `each'
    from /Users/redres/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/guard-2.4.0/lib/guard/guardfile/generator.rb:88:in `initialize_all_templates'
    from /Users/redres/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/guard-2.4.0/lib/guard/guardfile.rb:39:in `initialize_all_templates'
    from /Users/redres/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/guard-2.4.0/lib/guard/cli.rb:167:in `init'
    from /Users/redres/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/thor-0.18.1/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
    from /Users/redres/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/thor-0.18.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:120:in `invoke_command'
    from /Users/redres/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/thor-0.18.1/lib/thor.rb:363:in `dispatch'
    from /Users/redres/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/thor-0.18.1/lib/thor/base.rb:439:in `start'
    from /Users/redres/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/guard-2.4.0/bin/guard:6:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/redres/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/bin/guard:23:in `load'
    from /Users/redres/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/bin/guard:23:in `<main>'
    from /Users/redres/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
    from /Users/redres/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

**Edit:**

If I do `find /Users/redres/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484 | grep Guardfile` I get lots of hits

The .rvm/gems folder also contains these folders twice ruby-1.9.3-p484@global and ruby-1.9.3-p484. If I list the ruby versions, I get current, default and current && default.

I try'd `sudo chmod 777 -R /Users/redres/.rvm`, but then I get `chmod: -R: No such file or directory`

Comment: The `-R: No such file or directory` means that `-R` is not a file or directory. It seems that the options must go before the new mode or file. So `sudo chmod -R 777 /Users/redres/.rvm` is what you was trying to do. So, if there is a lot of `Guardfiles`, is there one that have the exact same path that the error is giving to you? If there is no Guardfile in that exact path, no point in changing permissions.

Answer (score 1):

The error says that the file `/Users/redres/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/guard-jasmine-headless-webkit-0.3.2/lib/guard/jasmineheadlesswebkit/templates/Guardfile` don't exists. Does it?

If yes, should be a permission problem.

If not, where the Guardfile should actually be? If you can't guess, try to run `find /Users/redres/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484 | grep Guardfile` for a full list of where it can currently exists. Chances are that you are using the wrong gemset/ruby version.

Comment: my guard is looking in the same path as you have here, but the actual path I have is `[..]/guard/jasmine-headless-webkit/templates/Guardfile`.